# ¿Como arrastrar datos de un datagrid a otro de diferentes forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en visual studio c#, que es la que se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero hacer es arrastrar el material del form materiales al form de color azul en la columna material para sustituir el valor, pero no me ha salido.

Comment: arrastrar? te referis a hacer un drag and drop?

Comment: creo que si, no conosco el nombre de esos eventos o propiedades

Comment: Bueno. Se llama drag and drop. Tenes eventos varios al iniciar el drag (desde los controles de origen ) y drop (a los controles destino). No es algo simple, pero tampoco ultra complejo. Empeza analizando esos eventos. Y probalo en un programa aparte, no suele ser simple hacer un debug de esos eventos.